# How would you remove a specific character between two words?

Tags: notepad++

I'm looking to do the following. I have 1400+ of these to do.

```
Application=M:\8TB+\GOG.Com\99_Levels_To_Hell\Launch_99_Levels_To_Hell.Lnk
WorkingFolder=M:\8TB+\GOG.Com\99_Levels_To_Hell\

ExitMethod=WinClose
```

I want to make it

```
Application=M:\8TB+\GOG.Com\99_Levels_To_Hell\Launch 99 Levels To Hell.Lnk
WorkingFolder=M:\8TB+\GOG.Com\99_Levels_To_Hell\

ExitMethod=WinClose
```

I only want to target the portion between "Launch" and "Lnk". Removing all the `_` in between.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Im getting closer. If there is a way to select all marked lines, then I got it. Ill just use the replace feature with selected.

Comment: Is it definitely only the last part you want to remove underscores from?

Answer (score 1):

## How can I replace a character in the last part of a path only on specific lines using Notepad++?

The best and possibly only way to go about it is regex. This took a bit of thinking about, but the following should work:

**Search**: `(?<!\\)(?!.*\\)_(?=.*Lnk)`

**Replace with**:

<sup>*(space character ↑)*</sup>

(in current/all documents; NB: ' '  is the space character)

### Explanation

- To match parts **after the last backslash**, we combine a negative lookbehind with a negative lookahead: `(?<!\\)(?!.*\\)`.

  <sup>*(I freely admit this part was a bit of black magic which I still don't fully understand- no `\` behind and no `\` followed by any characters ahead?)*</sup>
- Match the underscore: `_`
- You want to match only lines matching the `Application` shortcut, so we make sure the **line ends with '`Lnk`'** by using a negative lookahead: `(?=.*Lnk)`

### Summary

So altogether, it **matches underscores**, but only *after the last backslash* and *only on lines ending in 'Lnk'*. That is, `(?<!\\)(?!.*\\)_(?=.*Lnk)`

### Demo

[image: regex in action]

[Try it in regex101!](https://regex101.com/r/JEaEGV/1)

---

I could only use the lines you provided, but provided they satisfy those assumptions (operating on last part after backslash, underscores, and ending with 'Lnk') it should work grand for other lines too.